# Connect to server through proxy

Tags: http, go, http-proxy

I want to connect to a server through proxy server that I have. 
I am searching for something that is similar to Python's HTTPConnection.set_tunnel, is there something like this in golang?

----edit-----

I'm trying to create a connection to a server that allows self signed certificates & transfers through proxy, will this code work properly?

```
func CreateProxyClient(serverProxy string, sid string, portProxy int) (*Client, error) {
    http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    proxyUrl, _ := url.Parse(serverProxy+":"+strconv.Itoa(portProxy))
    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
    }
    var netClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
        Transport: tr,
    }
    return &Client{netClient, serverProxy, sid}, nil
}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`http.Transport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport), which can be set on an `http.Client`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` for HTTP or `HTTPS_PROXY` for HTTPS so the default http transport will use it.

Also as an alternative you can create `http.Transport` by yourself with `Proxy` field set to `http.ProxyURL` function call or use you custom implementation.

Example:

```
proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://proxy.example.com:port")
http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
}
// request using proxy
resp, _ := http.Get("https://google.com"))
```

Comment: Seems about right. I just want to see that I unserstand: the http.ProxyUrl function gets the proxy url as a parameter? and after doing that every request I'll send will go through the proxy server?

Comment: @DarkSkylo see example I've added

Comment: hey @yanzay, Thank you for all the help, please see the changes I made